# jQuery Animation Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, delay

How do I delay animation with jQuery?

I need to get a navigation to expand the width, and then expand the height, and then reversed for the reverse animation.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav li").not("#logo, #nav li ul li").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({width:"200px"},{queue:false,duration:1000});
    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({width:"30px"},{queue:false,duration:1000});
    });


    $("#nav li.parent").hover(function(){
        $(this).children("ul").animate({height:"40px"},{queue:false,duration:500});
    }, function(){
        $(this).children("ul").animate({height:"0px"},{queue:false,duration:500});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the jQuery `.delay(N)` methods, where N is the milliseconds to delay.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MadaraUchiha/YVk6Z/1)

Comment: I'm assuming your jsFiddle will clear this up, but where exactly does that bit of code go? I'm very new to jQuery so sorry about the noob questions

Comment: That goes between animations, I've added the jsFiddle, feel free to take a look.

Comment: Ahh, I see, but what about if I want it to be on two different hover states, like in my code example?

Comment: `.delay(N)` delays the execution of the script, you can put it anywhere, (before you start animating the reverse animation for example, or after you animate the normal one).

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, would you mind putting a simple example up on JSFiddle?

Comment: @Rev let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2240/discussion-between-rikudo-sennin-and-rev)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the call you are looking for http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
.delay(n) // where n is the millis of delay
```

use is as follows

```
$.animate(action1).delay(n).animate(action2)
// this code puts the delay bewtween two different animations
```