# How to add a loading animation to button?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, loading

I am very new to JavaScript, I need a help in adding a loading animation on the check button, so when user clicks on the check button the loading animation will delay for a while before the submit button slides down.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Click the "Check" button to unhide Submit Button</p>

        <div id="myDIV">
            CLICK CHECK BUTTON.
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
        </div>

        <div id="mynewDIV">
            SUBMIT BUTTON.
            <button>Submit</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById('mynewDIV');
            x.style.display = 'none';

            function myFunction() {
                var y = document.getElementById('myDIV');
                $("#myDIV").slideUp(1000);
                y.style.display = 'none';

                var y = document.getElementById('mynewDIV');
                $("#mynewDIV").slideDown(1000);
                y.style.display = 'block';

            }
        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: *‘i've literally searched the whole internet*’ No, no you haven't.

Comment: Unless the JQuery documentation for `slide` and `delay` is suddenly outside the internet, you haven't searched `literally the whole internet`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Animation Delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986655/jquery-animation-delay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

 <p>Click the "Check" button to unhide Submit Button</p>
<div id="loading">
  <p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" />
</div>
<div id="myDIV">
    CLICK CHECK BUTTON.
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
</div>

<div id="mynewDIV">
    SUBMIT BUTTON.
    <button>Submit</button>
</div>

<script>
            var x = document.getElementById('mynewDIV');
    x.style.display = 'none';

    var img = document.getElementById('loading');
    img.style.display = 'none';

    function myFunction() {
                   var y = document.getElementById('myDIV');
            $("#myDIV").slideUp("slow", function(){
              y.style.display = 'none';
              var img = document.getElementById('loading');
              img.style.display = 'block';
            });

            var y = document.getElementById('mynewDIV');
            $("#mynewDIV").delay(3000).slideDown("slow", function(){
              var img = document.getElementById('loading');
              img.style.display = 'none';
              y.style.display = 'block';
             });

        }
</script>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Please like i mentioned, i do not know how to integrate the code you linked me to into my code. Please if you can spare few minutes of your time and copy out my little code, please help me implement the loading animation on the "Check" button. I will be really greatful.

Comment: @HarrysonDaniels wait i am on it.

Comment: @HarrysonDaniels what you want tell me in detail

Comment: What i want is, when user clicks on the _check_ button in the `<div id="myDIV">` a spiner animation should appear on _check_ button showing that content is loading, before the `<div id="mynewDIV">` content will now slide down after few seconds.

Comment: Bro thanks alot for the effort. The check button was delayed but unfortunately there was no spine animation to tell user that it's loading before the submit <div> slides down. Please help me in adding this if u can.